# Unity Failed to Re-package Resources Error

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games, build-error

I am getting an error when i try to build my game for android. The error is :

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
>   C:\Users\halil.cosgun\Desktop\ADTBundle\adt_bundle\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/halil.cosgun/Desktop/ADTBundle/adt_bundle/sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.fusepowered.unitytest:com.google.android.gms:com.unity3d.player:com.google.android.gms -S "C:\Users\halil.cosgun\Desktop\Projects\AmbulanceFirstDeneme\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\FuseSDK\res" -S "C:\Users\halil.cosgun\Desktop\Projects\AmbulanceFirstDeneme\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res" -S "C:\Users\halil.cosgun\Desktop\Projects\AmbulanceFirstDeneme\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-6.5.87\res"

If I delete the play_game_services_libs folder (play_game_services.jar is in there), the build is successful. But, PlayGamesPlatform.Activate() code is not work. If I delete the FuseSDK, the build is successful. I know there is a conflict between this two plugins, but I didn't figure it out how I fix this problem.

Please help me.

Sincerely.

These are the screenshots my project folder :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but its possible that you have two versions of google-play-services. If im remember well you can have only one in entire project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I didn't know how I can solve this problem at first. I tried so many ways to solve this error. First of all, I updated my JDK to latest version.(jdk1.8.0.65 - 64bit) - Then I deleted play_game_services_6.5.8.7 and AndroidSupportV4 which is in Plugins/Android/ folder. After that I added FuseSDK prefab to main scene of my project. Finally I hit Build and Run.

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

Have a nice day! :)